# Can't access PHP array inside script localization from javascript

Tags: loop, javascript, user-meta, array, wp-localize-script

I have a loop to retrieve all users with the specific `meta_key` user values from `wp_user_meta` database and then put it in `wp_localize_script` array so I could access the data with Javascript and do my thing with it. Unfortunately, when I run the loop and put all the results to the variable, and try to console.log the results, I get just the string "Array" out in the console 3 times in one line, instead of the real values.

[image]

Here is my code:

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855');
function Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855(){

    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'quiz_scores'
    );

    $users = get_users($args);
    foreach($users as $user){
            echo "<pre>";
        print_r(get_user_meta ($user->ID));
                $veik .= get_user_meta ($user->ID);
            echo "</pre>";
    }
    if ( is_page_template('page-quiz.php') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'quiz', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '20151215', true );
                wp_localize_script('quiz', Questions_list, array(
                    'siteUrl' => get_option("question"),
                    "ans" => get_option("answer"),
                    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                    'usr_scr' => $veik
                ));
        }
}
```

`print_r(get_user_meta ($user->ID));` works just fine, I get my all 3 users printed out with the `meta_key` "quiz_scores". But when I put it in the variable and then use it inside script localize like this: `'usr_scr' => $veik` and try to console.log it in my other script.js file `console.log(Questions_list.usr_scr);` like I said, I get only string "Array" out in the console 3 times (as many times as there is users in database with that specific `meta_key` instead of the real value). I tried using `toString()` but it doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: please remove dot into this ($veik .=)

Comment: @PatelJignesh If I remove it, I get only last element from the loop to my variable, because on each iteration it gers overwritten.

Comment: define the variable  $veik = ' ' after that you can use like this $veik .= ' ' without  variable define can't use it like this.

Comment: `.=` is a string operator, you can't use it to append arrays.

Comment: @PatelJignesh I defined it first and used like this again `$veik .= get_user_meta ($user->ID);` but same problem

Comment: @Milo Any other ideas for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_user_meta` returns an array, so to get an array containing an array of each user's data, use `[]` to append:

```
foreach( $users as $user ){
    $veik[] = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
}
```